# document.getElementById().value not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, getelementbyid

I realize that similar questions have been asked here. However, mine is different in that I want to set a value in an element from a Javascript function.

The answers to similar questions were not fitting for my problem, and didn't solve it.

I have the following code:

```
function getItems() {
                        var sixOrLower = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
                        var higherThanSix = ["7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"];
                        var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
                        for(i=0; i<sixOrLower.length; i++){
                            document.getElementById(arr[i]).value = sixOrLower[i];
                        }

                        var arr2 = ["seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve",];
                        for(j=0; j<higherThanSix.length; j++){
                            document.getElementById(arr2[j]).value = higherThanSix[j];
                        }
                        document.getElementById("f").submit();
                }
```

sixOrLower and higherThanSix are arrays that are filled by another function that has no other purpose. This works fine.

Now I have a form that has hidden fields where I want to store the values from the code above:

```
<form class="f" id="f" name="f" action="<? echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" enctype=
      "multipart/form-data" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="one" id="one" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="two" id="two" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="three" id="three" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="four" id="four" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="five" id="five" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="six" id="six" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="seven" id="seven" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="eight" id="eight" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="nine" id="nine" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ten" id="ten" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="eleven" id="eleven" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="twelve" id="twelve" value="">
                    <button id="but_order" onclick="getItems();">Do stuff</button>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted I want to use the fields in a server side script. However, the hidden input fields are not being filled in Firefox. It works fine in Chrome and IE. So the question is: How can I fix this for Firefox?

Comment: `sixOrLower` and `higherThanSix` appear to have never been defined. Did you mean those to be `arr` and `arr2`? `all` and `allprice` are also not defined.

Comment: Sorry about that, I adjusted the code to make it more readable. sixOrLower and higherThanSix are already defined. So that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the button markup to be a specific type: 'button', instead of letting it default a 'submit' button this will solve your problem.

`<button id="but_order" type="button" onclick="getItems();">Do stuff</button>`

The problem that you are experiencing is that the only button defined in the form is defaulting to a 'submit' button and the form is then being submitted before the getItems() function is being called.

Here is an example solution: https://jsfiddle.net/nmiddleweek/8dpzkfqo/11/

Cheers,
Nick

Comment: If I give it a type="button", it doesn't do anything anymore. I can click the button, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Then perhaps the onclick handler can't 'see' the getItems() function. Are you getting any errors in the console when you click the button?